# Join two table and then search for the match

Tags: mysql

I have two table named security_questions and login. Columns in login tables are:

```
Username, Security_QA_ID, Security_Answer, Security_Attempts,Last_Login,Password_Attempts
```

where security_questions have:

```
ID, Name
```

where Security_QA_ID is referenced with ID

```
CREATE DEFINER=`satish`@`%` PROCEDURE `p_chkAnswer`(
IN sq VARCHAR(75),
IN sa VARCHAR(20) ,
IN uname VARCHAR(15) ,
out msg INT
)
BEGIN
select (COUNT(*) > 0) INTO @result from login join security_questions on Security_QA_ID = ID where User_Name=uname and Name=sq and Security_Answer=sa;
set msg = @result;
if @result = 1 Then
UPDATE login SET  Last_Login=now(),Password_Attempts=0 where User_Name=uname;
else
UPDATE login SET  Security_Attempts=Security_Attempts+1 where User_Name=uname;
End if;

END
```

but in every time only else part get executes. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your code is quite confusing and hard to read (for me at least), I simplified your statement into a single SELECT so that I can check if your select is correct, and it appears to be correct:

```
CREATE TABLE `login`
 ( User_Name text, 
   Security_QA_ID int(11),
   Security_Answer text,
   Security_Attempts datetime,
   Last_Login datetime,
   Password_Attempts int(11)
 );

CREATE TABLE `security_questions`
 (ID int(11), 
  Name text
  );

INSERT INTO login SET
 User_name = 'a',
 Security_QA_ID = 1,
 Security_Answer = 'c',
 Security_Attempts = NOW(),
 Last_Login = NOW(),
 Password_Attempts = 0;

INSERT INTO security_questions SET
 ID = 1,
 Name = 'b';
```

And the select

```
SELECT IF(COUNT(*) > 0, 1, 0) AS Authenticated
from (login)
LEFT join security_questions on Security_QA_ID = ID 
where User_Name='a' and Name='b' and Security_Answer='c'
```

Do you have to use this **DEFINER**? wouldn't it be easier to write PHP/Perl/etc code to check for **Authenticated** as being non-zero?

Comment: Thanks for your help  actually im quite a beginner in mySql. and i dont get what you try to do. What AS Authenticated does. its a keyword or what

Comment: I asked MySQL to **count()** how many records return from my **SELECT**. And return it as a variable called **Authenticated** ( I could have called it CountMePlease as well, it is just a name). My SQL just finds how many rows you got, 0 means user didn't provide the right answer, 1 or more means he gave the right answer.

Comment: same result. only else part is executing